# Need to change password for mysql in config.ini.php(5.4.12) in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I set up root password for mysql and I find out that I should also changed that password in config.ini.php for wamp to work, but in my version of php 5.4.12 I can't find that line in config.ini.php to change, that exist in earlier versions, I just have.

```
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: for wamp? I guess you mean for `phpmyadmin`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the path of the file you have to change  :

C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php

Comment: print the content of your config.inc.php

Comment: I printed it now in my question. Below i++; ther should be some other server configuration that I don't have.

Comment: reaplace the content of this file with:                                    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Comment: don't forget to restart your wampserver

Comment: i'm waiting your reply if ok or not

Comment: if that's not working for  you , try to reinstall your wampserver again and  set up your password correctly , Good luck

Comment: No it's not working. I also tried to set for verbose and host to localhost in this code.

Comment: When you change phpmyadmins config.inc.php you have to restart Apache to make it pick up the changes.